# Apache httpcomponents modules for Java +9

Tags: java, java-11, apache-httpcomponents, java-module, jlink

I'm working with a modular java project. To export the programm with `jlink` I need all the dependencies to be modular, but apache `httpcomponents` is not.

As I didn't find any `httpcomponents` with modular format (with the module descriptor), I'm trying to make them modular myself.

The problem is I've been with this for too long (more than a day). Starting with `httpclient`, I have to modularize also all its dependencies. Now I'm like in the 3rd level hierarchy and I don't know how many libs are left. Some of them are: `avalon.framework`, `logkit`, `log4j`, `javax.servlet.api`, etc...

The app uses apache to manage proxies, certificates and other things.

Is it convinient to keep going with the modularization? Or should I adapt all the code to use [Java 11 java.net.http](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/package-summary.html)?

Comment: *Is it convinient to keep going with the modularization?* - I believe that was expected in general form all the library maintainers, not just an individual to bear all that pain. But yeah, once you achieve that you might just be a happier person. Based on the community experience here(see [tag:java-http-client], adapting to `java.net.http` is not as convenient as using `httpcomponents` without modularisation.

Comment: If you find something that is already modularized, I would suggest going with that instead of basically having to re-write the entire library yourself